# strip all $_POST and $_GET from data

Tags: php, regex

I am looking for a preg_replace method to strip all `$_GET['whatever']` and all `$_POST['values']` from a string.

For example, if the string is:

```
$str = "this is some text with $_POST['foo'] within it - and some $_GET['bar'] as well";
```

I am wanting to have it return:

```
$str = "this is some text with within it - and some as well";
```

Thanks.

Comment: Cool, what do you have so far?

Comment: Isn't it possible to remove the $_POST and $_GET variables in your $str?

Comment: If it's about the invalid syntax, as presented here, and not the actual string content, then rather use your editors search and replace functions.

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/oI6kP2/1

Comment: A pattern like `/\$_(GET|POST)\[.+?\]/` should suffice

Comment: ...giggle, always funny all the SO folks that post comments that are not answers... yes, obviously my pseudocode was just that... pseudocode.

Comment: @Abela To be fair... you posted a question that didn't ask a question. If your question shows research effort and substantial attempt, the comments will be much more helpful.

Comment: Questions like this are often too simple to warrant posting a proper answer for, some basic research or attempts yourself to solve the question would've given you an answer. I don't want your rep for this, but I also don't want you to continue to scratch your head over and over again.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no research effort or attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assingnment you wrote won't even run, because the quotes inside the string will cause a syntax error. You need to escape them, e.g.

```
$str = 'this is some text with $_POST[\'foo\'] within it - and some $_GET[\'bar\'] as well';
```

Assuming you've done that, you can remove those strings with:

```
$str = preg_replace('/\$_(GET|POST)\[[^]]+\]/', '', $str);
```

This will work as long as you don't have any array references nested inside the brackets.

Comment: Don't need to escape the square bracket in the character class?

Comment: Not if it's the first thing in the class.

Comment: Oh, cool. Didn't know that one

Comment: Awesome, thank you @Barmar worked perfectly!  The quantifier is what had me stumped.